# Multiple If Condensing - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

So I have this code... (I'm sorry)

(I needed more "details" in my question as the code is so long)
Basically it takes the users hug count, and at intervals it gives them a new quote as a reward, but the intervals are irregular.

```
if ($hugs > 0) {
    $quote = $quotes[0];
}
if ($hugs > 5) {
    $quote = $quotes[1];
}
if ($hugs > 10) {
    $quote = $quotes[2];
}
if ($hugs > 20) {
    $quote = $quotes[3];
}
if ($hugs > 50) {
    $quote = $quotes[4];
}
if ($hugs > 100) {
    $quote = $quotes[5];
}
if ($hugs > 150) {
    $quote = $quotes[6];
}
if ($hugs > 200) {
    $quote = $quotes[7];
}
if ($hugs > 250) {
    $quote = $quotes[8];
}
if ($hugs > 500) {
    $quote = $quotes[9];
}
if ($hugs > 750) {
    $quote = $quotes[10];
}
if ($hugs > 1000) {
    $quote = $quotes[11];
}
if ($hugs > 1500) {
    $quote = $quotes[12];
}
```

As the intervals between the hug counts are irregular, is there a way to condense this down at all?

TIA.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a switch statement and cases. Just reverse the order of the if's from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly condense it! One way is to build an associative array (key-value pairings), like the example below.

```
/**
 * Returns a quote based on the number of hugs
 *
 * @param int $hugs
 * @param array $quotes
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
function getQuoteFromHugs($hugs, $quotes) {
    $hugs_quotes = array(
        1500 => $quotes[12],
        1000 => $quotes[11],
        750 => $quotes[10],
        500 => $quotes[9],
        250 => $quotes[8],
        200 => $quotes[7],
        150 => $quotes[6],
        100 => $quotes[5],
        50 => $quotes[4],
        20 => $quotes[3],
        10 => $quotes[2],
        5 => $quotes[1],
        0 => $quotes[0],
    );

    foreach($hugs_quotes as $hug_minimum => $quote) {
        if($hugs > $hug_minimum) {
            return $quote;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Usage
$quote = getQuoteFromHugs($hugs, $quotes);
```

This iterates through each key-value pairing in order and sees if your $hugs parameter is greater than the key. If so, it returns the value associated with that key.

Comment: Edited to include $quotes as a variable in the function call.
Works splendidly, thanks!

Comment: the reason I didn't do it like this is because I was worried it might not iterate in the order we want.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
$steps = array(0, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500);
foreach ($steps as $index => $step) {
    if ($hugs > $step) {
        $quote = $quotes[$index];
    }
}
```

This uses the `$steps` array to map the index in the `$quotes` array to the next step.

Comment: If you swap your comparison around, you can add a `break` in there and make it a tiny bit more efficient

Comment: Did you mean `foreach ($steps as ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to organize it:

```
function getQuote($hugs) {
    $hugQuotes = array(
        array(1500, $quotes[12]),
        array(1000, $quotes[11]),
        ...
    );

    foreach($hugQuotes as $v) {
        $c = $v[0];
        $quote = $v[1];
        if ($hugs > $c) return $quote;
    }

    return $quote;
}
```

Comment: Careful; your hugQuotes array isn't associative, so you won't get the result you'd expect!